# Creating Road Edge of Pavements from Road Centerlines Data using QGIS

Tags: qgis, road

Creating Road Edge of Pavements from Road Centerlines using QGIS
I have a Road Centerline data set and would like to use it to create a Road Edge Of Pavements data set that I could then export to a CAD format. Is there an easy way to do this in QGIS?

Comment: be sure to add an image of "Road Edge" to your question...